# Opening pdf data as image in rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have used Rails 4,

**views**

```
<div>
    <%=image_tag(some_method_path), class: 'image-view' %>
</div>
```

**controller method**

```
def some_method
 @label_image = Base64_incoded image hex
 send_data @label_image, :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline'
end
```

The image is not opening in view but it is opening as pdf if we run the url in window.

How to display the pdf as image in the div ?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, what you are trying to do is to render a preview into an image tag of a PDF document. However, this is not an automatic task, and your browser won't magically perform the conversion for you.

You need a library to render the PDF and capture a preview. This is not a Rails problem, it's a generic PDF conversion problem.

Note. This question is very similar to [How to have pdf viewer in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851614/how-to-have-pdf-viewer-in-ruby)